# Closed question has "{migrated}" in the title on the target site

Tags: bug, status-completed, migration, title

For example, [this question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/62646/what-are-the-main-uses-of-c-nowadays/62649) on Programmers was migrated in from Stack Overflow and subsequently closed. Now it says `[migrated]` in the title when it should still say `[closed]`.

Comment: I'm guessing the correct title should be [migrated, closed]. Good catch though.

Comment: @Khez An open migrated question doesn't show anything in the title on the destination site (which makes sense -- it's just another question far as that site is concerned), so I think just [closed] would be fine. I'm guessing the new feature doesn't identify if the post is on the destination site and just looks for closed migrated questions.

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/269026/backup-software)'s another example - the original is on SO, was pushed to SU where it was closed but is marked `[migrated]`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changed from

```
if (post.IsClosed)
   if (post.IsMigrated)
```

to

```
if (post.IsClosed)
   if (post.IsMigrated && post.ClosedDate <= post.MigrationDate)
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens (I assume) because the site uses the `MigrationDate` field to decide whether to show [migrated] or [closed], but `MigrationDate` is used both for the date the post was migrated to another site, as well as the date the post was migrated from another site (so it can show the "migrated from X site Y days ago" box)